# Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: php, laravel-5, automated-tests, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I have this code

```
@forelse($companies as $company)
             <div class="custom-control custom-radio">
                  <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="custom-control-input" type="radio" id="company-{{$company->id}}" value="{{$company->id}}" name="company_id" >
                          <label class="custom-control-label" for="company-{{$company->id}}">
                                            {{$company->name}}
                                        </label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

how I can test it using laravel dusk ???
I tried this

```
      $emailparts=explode('@',$userEmail);
      $companies=Company::select('companies.*')->whereRaw("SUBSTRING_INDEX(companies.email,'@',-1)='{$emailparts[1]}'")->get();
                ->select("company-".$companies->random()->id)
```

but its give me this error

```
Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body select[name='company-16']"}
```

How to fix it ??